# "If statement" to check if two different user ids match

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a problem with my if statement.

I wish to archive: 
 - If the sender id matches the user id = grant access
 - If the receiver id matches the user id = grant access

Currently I just have this:

```
if($pmData['sender_id']!=$userdata['id'] && $pmData['receiver_id']!=$userdata['id'])
    redirect("?i=a");
```

But as you can see, in this statement BOTH sender id AND receiver id much matches the user id.

How can I archive the other?

Comment: I surely need more info on how your site is structured, what the difference between sender and receiver is in this case. More info please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `or` / `||` instead of `&&` ?

```
if ($pmData['sender_id'] == $userdata['id'] || $pmData['receiver_id'] == $userdata['id']) {
    redirect("?i=a");
}
```

Comment: This just says unexpected "=="

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to combine the two with `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and).

Answer (score 2):

```
if($pmData['sender_id'] == $userdata['id'] || $pmData['receiver_id'] == $userdata['id']){
  // Grant Access
}
else{
  // Deny Access
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the variables are called `$sender` `$receiver` and `$user`:

```
if ($sender == $user || $receiver == $user) { allow(); }
else { forbid(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you simply need to replace the `&&` (AND) with a `||` (OR)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this. && means "Both must meet conditions". || means "One or the other must meet conditions".

Having || is like having two different if statements in one, && is like having an if statement inside an if statement in order to do something.